# How to override the "member enumeration" behavior of Collection objects in PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-3.0

Imagine that I have created a C# class that extended `Collection<T>` to add additional functionality for a specific use case.

```
public class MyCollection<T> : Collection<T> {}
```

Now, if I import this class into my PowerShell script, and instantiate such an object, calling member methods of the `T` object from said object will perform a sort of "magic" under-the-hood in which it calls the member method one after another for each item in the collection.

Note that in this example, the fact that I'm using my own `MyCollection[String]` instead of `Collection[String]` makes no difference.

```
Add-Type -Path ".\MyCollection.cs"
$test = New-Object -TypeName MyCollection[String]
$test.Add("one")
$test.Add("two")
$test.Add("three")
$test.Length
# 3
# 3
# 5
```

This behavior has more-or-less been dubbed "Member Enumeration". Go here for an explanation of what I'm talking about: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/

Since it's not actually running the ForEach-Object cmdlet (refer to the above link), I was hoping to find what is *actually* going on and how, if it's possible, I could override that behavior without making a hacky workaround (like creating a wrapper method in the MyCollection class for each method in the object's class).

For example:

```
public class MyCollection<T> : Collection<T> {
    public new void ForEach-Object(this Action action) {
        DoSomethingAsync(this, action);
    }
}
```

I'm intentionally using invalid syntax above in order to help make a point. I really have no idea if this can even be done.

Alternatively, if there is another way to achieve the same thing *without* doing the workaround I mentioned before, I would be interested in hearing those ideas as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, all of these collection types are going to implement the `IEnumerable` interface, which is using the [GetEnumerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_IEnumerable_GetEnumerator) method to iterate over the object collection, whether in a .NET `foreach` loop on in your PowerShell `Foreach-Object` cmdlet.

Some of the concrete Collection implementations are going to allow you to supply your own `GetEnumerator` implementation, while others aren't.  I can't think of ANY that do allow it off the top of my head, but I know `Collection<T>` does not.  If you need to override this functionality, you could try shadowing `GetEnumerator` with the `new` keyword as you're demonstrating above, and it should work just fine.  Another option is to write your own collection class that implements [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netframework-4.8), but that sounds like a pain.

Comment: This sounded really promising, but after trying it by creating a new GetEnumerator method to hide the base GetEnumerator method, running the member enumeration still only did its previous behavior. I will try to fiddle around a little more to see if I was missing something before potentially attempting to implement my own IEnumerable.

Comment: Okay, it turns out that I had to implement IList<T> in order for PowerShell to look at the IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator of my class rather than the base class. While that doesn't quite solve *my* problem, it does solve this question, and it did lead me to a potential solution for my particular problem.

Comment: Good feedback, glad it helped!  I was worried that shadowing the `GetEnumerator` method was going to yield unexpected results as  well, but it sounds like that didn't get in the way.

Answer (score 2):

**You can *not* prevent PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375)** (without also making your collection non-enumerable), given that it is behavior built into `.`, the member-access operator.

- However, **you can *bypass* it** with extra effort when you access a member, namely **via the [intrinsic `.psbase` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members?view=powershell-7.3#psbase)**:<sup>[1]</sup>

  ```sh
  ((Get-Item /), (Get-Item /)).Name         # Member(-access) enumeration
  ((Get-Item /), (Get-Item /)).psbase.Name  # NO enumeration, only the array's
                                            # own members.
  ```

However, **if you refer to a property that exists on the collection object itself, that collection-level property *is* used**, overriding member-access enumeration.

That is, `$test.Count` - given that `.Count` is an (instance) member of your collection type - would return just `3`, the number of elements in the collection.

[GitHub suggestion #7445](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7445) asks for a distinct syntax (operator) for member-access enumeration, but as long as PowerShell remains committed to backward compatibility (which may be forever), the behavior of `.` will not change.

---

<sup>[1] Note that the `.psbase` property only *mediates* member access that is restricted to the type-native members. The value of `.psbase` itself is a `[pscustomobject]` instance with an ETS (Extended Type System) name of `System.Management.Automation.PSMemberSet`.</sup>

Comment: So basically your answer is "currently, no." Because the suggestion you're offering seems the same as the hacky solution I mentioned—i.e., creating a wrapper method in the MyCollection class for each method in the object's class. Unless I can figure out a way to abstract that, that will become a lot of duplicated code. +1 for that GitHub suggestion. It is interesting, though it's unfortunate that we may never see it implemented.

Comment: @Shenk: More generally: No just currently no, but no as long as PowerShell remains committed to backward compatibility, which may well be forever. I didn't mean to offer a suggestion, because there is no solution, if you want your collection to remain enumerable by standard means. (Of course, you can define your own custom enumeration method without implementing `IEnumerable` or perhaps even define your own enumeration interface that your classes then implement - but no code expecting `IEnumerable`s will work with them - and you won't be able to derive from `Collection<T>`).